# Side effects after increasing MAX_FILE_SIZE in Simple HTML Dom Parser?

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have just one small question related to the great software simplehtmldom parser.

Is it safe to increase the MAX_FILE_SIZE from default 600000 to e.g. 100 * 600000 ?

I know increasing it will need more memory and so on, but could it be that there are other side effects that will break the actual dom parsing ?

---

*Background Info:*

I'm processing some 'kind of huge' html files. 500Kb up to 5Mb! I need change some tags and remove some unwanted stuff. The source html files are valid html and therefore simplehtml was the best and probably easiest solution to use.

The main problem why I ask is that with the default settings the function `str_get_html(...)` will return false when the document is bigger than

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
```

which is defined by the simplehtml dom parser.

I can of course increase this value and after that everything works fine.
I'm just afraid of any side effects that may happen. Like choking some tags or other nasty stuff.

Comment: Hey ! I tried it 2 days ago ... it crushed my laptop with 3 000 000 hahaha ! I went back to 600 000 !
You should try for your own case on your localhost to see what happens !